# Why have nvm related commands —nvm, node, npm— stopped working?

Tags: shell, command-line, config, nvm, dotfiles

```
os: macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)
terminal app: Hyper 1.3.3.1754
nvm: 0.33.2
```

I installed `nvm`, according to the instruction, sometime ago without issue. Recently, it and the commands it's responsible for —`node` and `npm`— stopped working.

nvm/npm/node command not found

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this occurred because I recently switched my system default shell from bash to zsh —`chsh -s /bin/zsh`— without addressing the contents of `~/.bash_profile` which is sourced by `bash` but not `zsh`.

The [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) install script
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash`
places the following in the appropriate config file —one of: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc`.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

At time of install I used `bash` and that bit was placed in `~/.bash_profile`. Coping that content over to `~/.zshrc` got the commands working again.